# Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre « se tromper » et « avoir tort »?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre « se tromper » et « avoir tort »?

Et en pratique, l'un est-il plus utilisé que l'autre?

Comment: On peut parfois avoir raison de se tromper...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subtle one: *se tromper* is to make a mistake, *avoir tort* is to be wrong.

When you say *avoir tort*, there's an implication that the subject does or should feel regret or remorse in the eyes of the speaker. No such implication when you say *se tromper*, which can sometimes be benign.

Additionally *se tromper* is by definition unintentional, whereas *avoir tort* can sometimes be the result of a (wrong) intention.

For example you'd say

> Jean s'est trompé de chemin, mais ce n'est pas grave car ça n'a pas pris plus longtemps.

This means that Jean made a mistake, and intended to take another route, but the mistake ended up having no consequence to the speaker.

> Jean a eu tort de prendre ce chemin, car il y avait des embouteillages sur la route.

This means that Jean made a conscious choice to take a certain route, but it turned out not to be the best one in the end, so the speaker is feeling that Jean should have gone another way.